# iPod/iPhone USB Product IDs

Tags: ios, cocoa, usb, iokit

Is there a list somewhere of all Apple USB product IDs? I use IOKit to get notifications for attached/detached USB devices and would like to identify the device. Currently I get the device name and search for "iPod" and "iPhone" but I guess that's not really safe since it could also be an accessory (or could it?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this [USB Product ID](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) list but unfortunately it's not complete

Answer (score 4):

See the links below. Note that a device will have different product IDs, depending on the mode that it is in.  Also, multiple devices share IDs for DFU mode and Recovery mode, so you won't be able to fully tell them apart.

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Normal_Mode

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Recovery_Mode_%28Protocols%29

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=DFU_Mode

Comment: Yes but these lists are not complete either since they do not cover all iProducts since the first (not the very first, but those back in the day) iPods.